# Regex search to enforce copyright headers

Tags: regex, icu

I am using a static analysis tool on my codebase that allows setting custom rules via regex that will trigger warnings in my IDE.

What is a regular expression used to trigger a warning for any file that doesn't use my company's official copyright header?

```
/**
 Copyright © 2016 MyCompany. All rights reserved.
 */
```

I have tried the following:

```
(?!\A\/\*\*\n Copyright © 2016 MyCompany. All rights reserved\.\n \*\/)
```

but it seems to match every line as a warning.

Comment: I'm glad you've solved your problem, because there's not enough here for us to answer the question.  Recommending closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out my minor issue. I should put `\A` *before* the negative look-ahead:

```
\A(?!\/\*\*\n Copyright © 2016 MyCompany. All rights reserved\.\n \*\/)
```

`\A`: only search at the start of the file

`(?!your_pattern)`: means negative look-ahead for `your_pattern` aka return true if the pattern is NOT found

`\/\*\*\n`: look for `/**` and then newline character (need to escape `/` and `*` with the `\`)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why actually you need Look-ahead assertions. But, simple expression would work

> (^(/**). Copyright © 2016 MyCompany. All rights reserved.. */)
>   with s option(dot matches all)